# UICollectionView poor scrolling performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The problem I encounter is that whenever a row goes out of view, the scroll has a very fast and short lag.

This is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Saints *note = nil;
    int aX=0;
    int aY=0;

       note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];

        }
        else  if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
              [view removeFromSuperview];

        }}


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImage *imgbackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"today-left-side-images-bg.png"];

   NSArray *messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"random-saint-text-bg-brown.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-brightblue.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-green.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-grey.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-lightblue.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-lime.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-purple.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-red.png",@"random-saint-text-bg-teal.png",nil];
    int randNum = arc4random() % [messages count];

    NSString *returnValue =  [messages objectAtIndex:randNum];


    NSString *rndBGImg= returnValue;
    UIImage *imgbackgroundlower = [UIImage imageNamed:rndBGImg];


    UIImageView *imgViewlower = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgbackgroundlower];
    //imgViewlower.frame=CGRectMake(aX, aY+140, 140,73);
    imgViewlower.frame=CGRectMake(aX+4, aY+114, 119,43);


UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgbackground];

  imgView.frame=CGRectMake(aX, aY, 127,162);

    UIImageView *imgSaintPic = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgSaintPic.tag=1;
    imgSaintPic.frame=CGRectMake(aX+6, aY+6, 114,145);
    //NSString *imgname = [aDic objectForKey:@"saint_image"];
    NSString *imgname = note.saint_imagethumbnail;
    UIImage *tempimg= [UIImage imageNamed:imgname];
    [imgSaintPic setImage:tempimg];

    UILabel *lblNamelocal=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    NSString *strSaintName=note.saint_name;
    //lblNamelocal.text=strSaintName;
    if([note.saint_title length]>1)
        lblNamelocal.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",note.saint_title,strSaintName];
    else
        lblNamelocal.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strSaintName];


    //lblNamelocal.frame = CGRectMake(aX+6, aY+109, 116,30);
    [lblNamelocal sizeToFit];
    lblNamelocal.frame = CGRectMake(aX+5, aY+115, 118,26);
    lblNamelocal.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblNamelocal.numberOfLines = 0;

    lblNamelocal.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblNamelocal.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblNamelocal.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:11 ];
    // lblNamelocal.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblNamelocal.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
    lblNamelocal.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    lblNamelocal.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0.5);
    lblNamelocal.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;




    UILabel *lblsubtitle=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    //NSString *strSaintSubtitle=[aDic objectForKey:@"saint_title"];
    lblsubtitle.text=note.saint_subtitle;

    //lblsubtitle.frame = CGRectMake(aX+6, aY+132, 116, 25);
    lblsubtitle.frame = CGRectMake(aX+5, aY+140, 113, 20);
    lblsubtitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblsubtitle.numberOfLines = 2;


    lblsubtitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblsubtitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblsubtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
    // Removed CJamesRun lblsubtitle.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblsubtitle.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    lblsubtitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0.5);
    lblsubtitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    imgViewlower.tag=3;
    lblNamelocal.tag=2;
    lblsubtitle.tag=4;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgSaintPic];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgViewlower];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblNamelocal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblsubtitle];


  //  cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    return cell;
}
```

What I've tired is to rasterize the cell layer, and also to remove the views from the SuperView upon creating a new cell.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting up your cells' subviews just once, and then only updating the contents inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. E.g. you're loading some images in each cell, but those are the same for every cell, so loading them every time the cell is reused is unnecessary.

Comment: To go along with this answer, he should subclass UICollectionViewCell so that it comes set up with his views. Then he can just set the appropriate properties (images for image views, text for labels).

Comment: Thanks. It's a great addition and is the right way of dealing with the collection cells.